# NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter returns null, when android application starts on BOOT_COMPLETED intent

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc, bootcompleted

NFC based Android application, which starts after boot complete (when `BOOT_COMPLETED` event received by BroadcastReceiver).

### The Problem

Some times `NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this)` retunrs null; this is random/inconsistent, for some boot cycles it works fine and returns `NfcAdapter`, and for other boot cycles this method returns null.

I am suspecting, when it returns null, NFC Service not yet started, or NFC Service not fully running by the time `BOOT_COMPLETED` event is Broadcasted.

### The question

Is there a way to make sure NFC Service is running and stable before `BOOT_COMPLETED` event is Broadcasted?

Assuming the device is rooted, would it help if `init.rc` modified? If yes, What is the tweak if any one has come across such a problem?